# Uniqueness of A Field From Its Divergence and Curl

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

In my EM textbook, the author says that a vector field can be determined if we know both its divergence and curl *(Griffith's Electrodynamics, 3rd edition, page 273, section 6.3.2)*. For example, for the electrostatic field:

\begin{split}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}&=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E}&=0
\end{split}

Given these two equations, the $\mathbf{E}$ field can be solved for.

My question is: Is the vector field determined from its divergence and curl unique? If yes, what is the name of the theorem for this uniqueness?

Comment: Yup. To read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

Comment: Warning: E is only defined up to the gradient of a harmonic function.